# What is the [vimrc] tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, it seems to be used (very intermittently) for questions involving code which *could* be placed in a vimrc file, for questions for which the answer involves putting some code in your vimrc file, and for questions where the asker couldn't think of/be bothered to use more appropriate tags: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vimrc

i.e. it has no meaning. This doesn't seem all that useful to me.

I'd be happy to help clean up its use, if I had a good idea of what the community thinks it *should* be used for.

Improved tag info for that tag would probably help, too.

Comment: In Dutch we have a saying: "mopping the floor with the  
tap running". That perfectly describes my experience trying to clean up the vimrc tag.

Comment: Hah! Great saying. Bearing that in mind, I don't think the vimrc tag serves any real purpose. Seems like a candidate for blacklisting?

Comment: There are cases where it's applicable, such as questions about vimrc loading order and whatnot, but those are just a handful. We could perhaps tag those with [tag:config] and then nuke [tag:vimrc]. Unfortunately mods can't nuke tags either :-(

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That would be my preferred option, but I wasn't aware it required a developer to blacklist tags. And from reading [their description of the criteria required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/146632) for the less-impactful action of burnination it seems like they might not consider it *harmful* enough to do so, even if everyone generally agreed the tag were pointless. Ah well.